# javascript for-in loop in an Array

Tags: javascript

If the code is this:

```
arr=Array("a","b","c");
for(i in arr);
{
 alert(i);
}
```

there is no any alert,but if it is this:

```
arr=new Array("a","b","c");
for(i in arr)
{
 alert(i);//alerts 0,1,2
}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: There shouldn't be a `;` before the `{` in the for/in loop

Comment: @David try it in Internet explorer.I just tested in chrome there is no alert for the first snippet

Comment: @phihag try it with IE and there is no alert in chrome for first snippet ,i just tried it

Answer (score 3):

`Array` is a constructor.  To create a new object you should be using the new operator to create the object, which the constructor is then bound to and run against.  In this case though, it actually should work either way, your issue is most likely related to the semicolons next to your for-loop, as noted in the comments.

As an aside, for creating a new array its generally advised to use the simpler notation

```
var arr = ["a","b","c"];
```

Its also questionable to use a for-in loop with an array in javascript, as that will hit any additional properties defined on the array. (so if you said `arr.x = 2` it would also iterate over `x`.

Better to use the iterative form

```
var i =0, length =arr.length;
for ( ;i<length; i++) {

    alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: or `arr.forEach(function(value){alert(value);});`.

Comment: That's is the way to do it indeed, but not the cause of the OP's problems. The real cause is the semicolon after the `for` statement, ending it. The Array constructor can be called without `new`, and will construct a new array nevertheless (see ES5 [15.4.1.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.1.1))

Comment: yep, I realized that after my initial answer.  Changed the 1st paragraph to reflect it, kept the answer because I still think its useful for the OP and is a bit lengthy for a comment.

Comment: Another reason to not use `for...in` on arrays is that [the order items are processed is not guaranteed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#arrayNote). If you do use `for...in` to loop over anything, an array or object, you should always use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) on each property.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting different results is that you were using incorrect syntax for your for/in loops.

```
for(i in arr);
{
 alert(i);
}
```

should not have the first semicolon.

Also note that a nicer way to iterate over an array would be:

```
arr.forEach(function(value, index){
    alert(value); // or alert(index);
});
```

As bfavaretto has mentioned.

Invoking the Array function without the `new` keyword will Create and return a new Array object in the same way it would had you used the `new` keyword.

So these two will alert the same things:

```
arr1 = new Array("a","b","c");
arr2 = Array("a","b","c");
```